# Where can I see the trace and event in Azure AppInsights?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I have the following console app.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TelemetryConfiguration config = TelemetryConfiguration.CreateDefault();
        config.ConnectionString = "bla bla";
        var client = new TelemetryClient(config);
        client.TrackEvent("TestEvent");
        client.TrackTrace("Eriks test trace");
        client.Flush();
    }
```

How can I view the event and trace log in Azure portal? If I go to the application insights resource and the Monitoring -> Logs, I have to choose a scope. I don't know what to choose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the azure portal, navigate to the application insights resource and choose "Transaction Search" from the menu. For events there is also a dedicated "Events" menu item for a specialized view.

[image]